# How to copy all the shared conan libraries into the build folder?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have custom conan packages that output c++ shared libraries. (dylib or dll)
Whenever I build my CMake project I would like all these shared libraries to be copied to the directory where the executable is.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `imports` method of a `conanfile.txt` or `conanfile.py` that you use in your CMake project.

Here the documentation: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#imports

With a`conanfile.py` it look like this

```py
def imports(self):
   self.copy("*.dll", "", "bin")
   self.copy("*.dylib", "", "lib")
```

and with a `conanfile.txt` (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile_txt.html?highlight=imports#imports)

```
[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./bin # Copies all dll files from packages bin folder to my local "bin" folder
lib, *.dylib* -> ./bin # Copies all dylib files from packages lib folder to my local "bin" folder
```

With that you should be able to have your binaries inside your build folder.

After that you only need to use the `file` function in CMake to copy your lib where you want to. [Documenation for `file` function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy-file)
You will certainly use something like this

```
file(COPY_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib.dll <path_to_exe>)
```

Comment: Conan deletes any copied files in `imports()` after it finishes `build()`.  The `keep_imports=True` attribute (https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#keep-imports) should be set to prevent this.